# Check whether the ARReferenceImage is no longer visible in the camera's view

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, aranchor

I would like to check whether the [ARReferenceImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage) is no longer visible in the camera's view. At the moment I can check if the image's node is in the camera's view, but this node is still visible in the camera's view when the [ARReferenceImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage) is covered with another image or when the image is removed.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    guard let node = self.currentImageNode else { return }

    if let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView {
        let isVisible = sceneView.isNode(node, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView)
        print("Is node visible: \(isVisible)")
    }
}
```

So I need to check if the image is no longer visible instead of the image's node visibility. But I can't find out if this is possible. The first screenshot shows three boxes that are added when the image beneath is found. When the found image is covered (see screenshot 2) I would like to remove the boxes.

[image: Found image with boxes]

[image: Convered image with boxes]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem! Used a little bit of Maybe1's code and his concept to solving the problem, but in a different way. The following line of code is still used to reactivate the image recognition.

```
// Delete anchor from the session to reactivate the image recognition
sceneView.session.remove(anchor: anchor)
```

Let me explain. First we need to add some variables.

```
// The scnNodeBarn variable will be the node to be added when the barn image is found. Add another scnNode when you have another image.    
var scnNodeBarn: SCNNode = SCNNode()
// This variable holds the currently added scnNode (in this case scnNodeBarn when the barn image is found)     
var currentNode: SCNNode? = nil
// This variable holds the UUID of the found Image Anchor that is used to add a scnNode    
var currentARImageAnchorIdentifier: UUID?
// This variable is used to call a function when there is no new anchor added for 0.6 seconds    
var timer: Timer!
```

The complete code with comments below.

```
/// - Tag: ARImageAnchor-Visualizing
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

    // The following timer fires after 0.6 seconds, but everytime when there found an anchor the timer is stopped.
    // So when there is no ARImageAnchor found the timer will be completed and the current scene node will be deleted and the variable will set to nil
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if(self.timer != nil){
            self.timer.invalidate()
        }
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.6 , target: self, selector: #selector(self.imageLost(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    // Check if there is found a new image on the basis of the ARImageAnchorIdentifier, when found delete the current scene node and set the variable to nil
    if(self.currentARImageAnchorIdentifier != imageAnchor.identifier &&
        self.currentARImageAnchorIdentifier != nil
        && self.currentNode != nil){
            //found new image
            self.currentNode!.removeFromParentNode()
            self.currentNode = nil
    }

    updateQueue.async {

        //If currentNode is nil, there is currently no scene node
        if(self.currentNode == nil){

            switch referenceImage.name {
                case "barn":
                    self.scnNodeBarn.transform = node.transform
                    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.scnNodeBarn)
                    self.currentNode = self.scnNodeBarn
                default: break
            }

        }

        self.currentARImageAnchorIdentifier = imageAnchor.identifier

        // Delete anchor from the session to reactivate the image recognition
        self.sceneView.session.remove(anchor: anchor)
    }

}
```

Delete the node when the timer is finished indicating that there was no new ARImageAnchor found.

```
@objc
    func imageLost(_ sender:Timer){
        self.currentNode!.removeFromParentNode()
        self.currentNode = nil
    }
```

In this way the currently added scnNode wil be deleted when the image is covered or when there is found a new image.

[image]

This solution does unfortunately not solve the positioning problem of images because of the following:

> ARKit doesn’t track changes to the position or orientation of each detected image.

Comment: In ARKit 2.0 we have the option to track images, you just have to use a `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` and add the images to the `trackingImages` variable.

Comment: I know, saw the ARKit 2.0 announcement! Thanks anyway

Comment: Such an awesome answer, should have more upvotes. I could perfectly use that in my project. Thank you!

Comment: Just a quick question, `updateQueue.async` is showing `use of unresolved identifier` to me, why? Can I use `DispatchQueue.main,async` instead?

Comment: @KNV Hey can you check this question for a moment pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239089/ar-refernce-image-plane-was-not-position-properly-in-ios-swift

Comment: Thank you so much! Based on your idea, I managed to solve it with Unity ARKit plugin using coroutines.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this is currently possible.

From the [Recognizing Images in an AR Experience documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience):

> *Design your AR experience to use detected images as a starting point for virtual content.*
>
> **ARKit doesn’t track changes to the position or orientation of each detected image**. If you try to place virtual content that stays attached to a detected image, that content may not appear to stay in place correctly. Instead, use detected images as a frame of reference for starting a dynamic scene.

---

### New Answer for iOS 12.0

ARKit 2.0 and iOS 12 finally adds this feature, either via `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` or via the `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.detectionImages` property that now also tracks the position of the images.

The Apple documentation to `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` lists advantages of both methods:

> With ARImageTrackingConfiguration, ARKit establishes a 3D space not by tracking the motion of the device relative to the world, but solely by detecting and tracking the motion of known 2D images in view of the camera. ARWorldTrackingConfiguration can also detect images, but each configuration has its own strengths:
>
> - World tracking has a higher performance cost than image-only tracking, so your session can reliably track more images at once with ARImageTrackingConfiguration.
> - Image-only tracking lets you anchor virtual content to known images only when those images are in view of the camera. World tracking with image detection lets you use known images to add virtual content to the 3D world, and continues to track the position of that content in world space even after the image is no longer in view.
> - World tracking works best in a stable, nonmoving environment. You can use image-only tracking to add virtual content to known images in more situations—for example, an advertisement inside a moving subway car.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Note it's not just `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.detectionImages` that gets you live tracking of images (in a world tracking session) — you also need to set `maximumNumberOfTrackedImages` to nonzero.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to check if an image that you are tracking is not currently tracked by ARKit is by using the "isTracked" property in the ARImageAnchor on the didUpdate node for anchor function.

For that, I use the next struct:

```
struct TrackedImage {
    var name : String
    var node : SCNNode?
}
```

And then an array of that struct with the name of all the images.

```
var trackedImages : [TrackedImage] = [ TrackedImage(name: "image_1", node: nil) ]
```

Then in the didAdd node for anchor, set the new content to the scene and also add the node to the corresponding element in the array of trackedImages

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    // Check if the added anchor is a recognized ARImageAnchor
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{
        // Get the reference ar image
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
        // Create a plane to match the detected image.
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        // Create SCNNode from the plane
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        // Add the plane to the scene.
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        // Add the node to the tracked images
        for (index, trackedImage) in trackedImages.enumerated(){
            if(trackedImage.name == referenceImage.name){
                trackedImage[index].node = planeNode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in the didUpdate node for anchor function we search for the anchor name in our array and check if the property isTracked is false.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    var trackedImages : [TrackedImage] = [ TrackedImage(name: "image_1", node: nil) ]
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{
        // Search the corresponding node for the ar image anchor
        for (index, trackedImage) in trackedImages.enumerated(){
            if(trackedImage.name == referenceImage.name){
                // Check if track is lost on ar image
                if(imageAnchor.isTracked){
                    // The image is being tracked
                    trackedImage.node?.isHidden = false // Show or add content
                }else{
                    // The image is lost
                    trackedImage.node?.isHidden = true // Hide or delete content
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution works when you want to tracked multiple images at the same time and know when any of them is lost.

Note: For this solution to work the `maximumNumberOfTrackedImages` in the AR configuration must be set to a nonzero number.

Comment: Where is the property of imageAnchor.isTracked found?

Comment: @JoshRobbins It is found on the ARTrackable protocol, and because the ARImageAnchor conforms to the ARTrackable protocol you can found it on any ARImageAnchor instance. Here you can found more about it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable/2928210-istracked

Comment: I have a slightly different setup but managed to use the didUpdate suggestion to track when an image is tracked or loses its tracking. Upvoting the answer based on that.

Answer (score 5):

For what its worth, I spent hours trying to figure out how to constantly check for image references. The didUpdate function was the answer. Then you just need to test of the reference image is being tracked using the .isTracked property. At that point, you can set the .isHidden property to true or false. Heres my example:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        let trackedNode = node

        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{

        if (imageAnchor.isTracked) {
            trackedNode.isHidden = false
            print("\(trackedNode.name)")

        }else {
            trackedNode.isHidden = true

            //print("\(trackedImageName)")
            print("No image in view")

        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I have understood what your asking (so apologies), but if I have then perhaps this might help...

It seems that for `insideOfFrustum` to work correctly, that their must be some `SCNGeometry` associated with the node for it to work (an SCNNode alone will not suffice).

For example if we do something like this in the `delegate` callback and save the added `SCNNode` into an array:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
    guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    //2. Print The Anchor ID & It's Associated Node
    print("""
        Anchor With ID Has Been Detected \(currentImageAnchor.identifier)
        Associated Node Details = \(node)
        """)


    //3. Store The Node
    imageTargets.append(node)
}
```

And then use the `insideOfFrustum` method, 99% of the time it will say that the node is in view even when we know it shouldn't be.

However if we do something like this (whereby we create a transparent marker node e.g. one that has some geometry):

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
    guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    //2. Print The Anchor ID & It's Associated Node
    print("""
        Anchor With ID Has Been Detected \(currentImageAnchor.identifier)
        Associated Node Details = \(node)
        """)


    //3. Create A Transpanrent Geometry
    node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.clear

    //3. Store The Node
    imageTargets.append(node)
}
```

And then call the following method, it does detect if the `ARReferenceImage` is inView:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

    //1. Get The Current Point Of View
    guard let pointOfView = augmentedRealityView.pointOfView else { return }

    //2. Loop Through Our Image Target Markers
    for addedNode in imageTargets{

        if  augmentedRealityView.isNode(addedNode, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView){
            print("Node Is Visible")
        }else{
            print("Node Is Not Visible")
        }

    }

}
```

In regard to your other point about an SCNNode being occluded by another one, the `Apple Docs` state that the `inViewOfFrostrum`:

> does not perform occlusion testing. That is, it returns
>   true if the tested node lies within the specified viewing frustum
>   regardless of whether that node’s contents are obscured by other
>   geometry.

Again, apologies if I haven't understood you correctly, but hopefully it might help to some extent...

**Update:**

Now I fully understand your question, I agree with @orangenkopf that this isn't possible. Since as the docs state:

> ARKit doesn’t track changes to the position or orientation of each
>   detected image.

Comment: Unfortunately you understood my question not correct. No worries, I have updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Recognizing Images in an AR Experience documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience):

> ARKit adds an image anchor to a session exactly once for each
>   reference image in the session configuration’s detectionImages array.
>   If your AR experience adds virtual content to the scene when an image
>   is detected, that action will by default happen only once. To allow
>   the user to experience that content again without restarting your app,
>   call the session’s remove(anchor:) method to remove the corresponding
>   ARImageAnchor. After the anchor is removed, ARKit will add a new
>   anchor the next time it detects the image.

So, maybe you can find a workaround for your case:

Let's say we are that structure which saves our `ARImageAnchor` detected and the virtual content associated:

```
struct ARImage {
    var anchor: ARImageAnchor
    var node: SCNNode
}
```

Then, when the `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` is called, you save the image detected into a temporary list of ARImage:

```
...

var tmpARImages: [ARImage] = []

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

        // If the ARImage does not exist
        if !tmpARImages.contains(where: {$0.anchor.referenceImage.name == referenceImage.name}) {
            let virtualContent = SCNNode(...)
            node.addChildNode(virtualContent)

            tmpARImages.append(ARImage(anchor: imageAnchor, node: virtualContent))
        }


        // Delete anchor from the session to reactivate the image recognition
        sceneView.session.remove(anchor: anchor)    
}
```

If you understood, while your camera's view point out of the image/marker, the delegate function will loop endlessly...  (*because we removed the anchor from the session*).

The idea will be to combine the image recognition loop, the image detected saved into the tmp list and the `sceneView.isNode(node, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView)` function to determine if the image/marker detected is no longer view.

I hope it was clear...

Comment: When the anchor is removed, the node associated with it is also removed. Since the virtualContent is added to that specific node, the virtualContent is no longer visible. So this approach does not work or I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

This code works only if You hold the device strictly horizontally or vertically. If You hold iPhone tilted or starting to tilt if, this code doesn't work:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

    //1. Get The Current Point Of View
    guard let pointOfView = augmentedRealityView.pointOfView else { return }

    //2. Loop Through Our Image Target Markers
    for addedNode in imageTargets{

        if  augmentedRealityView.isNode(addedNode, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView){
            print("Node Is Visible")
        }else{
            print("Node Is Not Visible")
        }

    }

}
```